# Create with javascript series of numbers increments starting with rounded number to the closest hundred

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is to generate a series beginning with a first number I input by rounding it to the first superior hundred (for example if number= 456, then first number in the series will be 500), then increment 200 by 200 until a number I give for example 2000.

For example if number I get is 758, and if i set limit_number to 2000 then i need to generate with javascript the following series and add it to the piece of code:

```
$('img').attr('data-stoppoints', '800,1000,1200, 1400, 1600,1800, 2000');
```

As you see the generated series of numbers need to be separated by commas.

So far my code is

```
var number = (screen.Width)
var rounded_number=Math.ceil(number/100)*100
$('img').attr('data-stoppoints', rounded_number,'<I don't know here what to write');
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Create a seperate function for this, round your number make a loop to fill an array until your second number and return this array as string with comma delimeter.

Comment: You could be fancier but why not just loop and do exactly as you describe ? When there's no built-in, you have to write the boring code.

Comment: i'm pretty beginner i would not know how to do this:)

Comment: i'll investigate

Comment: This is an excellent learning exercise . Research rounding numbers.. figure that part out first....easy web search. If you get answer given to you you will learn a lot less than working on it yourself.

Comment: To help you start: here's how you would round: `var value=Math.ceil(initialValue/100)*100`. Then do a loop with `value` as increment count and fill your array in the loop.

Comment: rounding to 100 is not my issue: i used Math.ceil(number/100)*100, it's more how to create a written series of number incremented of 200 with a limit of 2000 (variable itself)

Comment: i'll try, you're right, good exercise

Comment: should have mentioned you had the rounding part already figured out...then been more specific about problems you have in next step. Lots of ways to build the loop needed for the rest

Comment: corrected, you see iterations/loops i kind of know how to iterate the number but usually in loop (while, for...), the numbers are looped until one if "outputed". here i need eahc of them to be kept and written down in the list:)

Comment: try a `while()` loop... a `for()` loop can also be used `for(var i=number; i>smallest, i-200){ /*process i*/}` ..

Comment: fill in there: https://gist.github.com/Canop/5d0dc64cccaaff04ae2d15626217a596 ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use a helper function that produces an array of values (range):

```js
function range(start, stop, step = 1, roundTo = 1) {
    result = [];
    for (var i = Math.ceil(start / roundTo) * roundTo; i < stop; i += step) {
        result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
}

$('img').data('stoppoints', range(468, 1600, 200, 100).join(','));
//                          ^^^^ start,stop,step,round

console.log($('img').data('stoppoints'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img>
```

Note that jQuery has a `data` method that works well with `data-` attributes, so I would use that instead of `attr`.

Comment: congrats for breaking the effort of about everybody.

Comment: @Denys, i'll go deepen my javascript knowledge anyway, you're right, need to exercise to understand:)

Comment: @Mathieu It's not really about javascript, it's about programming, about how to dive into a problem and not just stare at it.

Comment: Denys i am used to diving...i'm in the middle of a 3 days dive:) and this detail helped me go on woith the dive... Totally agree with you got to get hands dirty and really analyze stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this function as `generateSeries(number)` where you have written `rounded_number`, like so :

```
var number = (screen.Width)
$('img').attr('data-stoppoints',generateSeries(number));
```

The `generateSeries` function. (You'll need to add this code snippet to your JS. Adjust the variables `limit` and `increment` as desired) :

```
generateSeries = function(number) {
    var limit = 2000;
    var increment = 200;
    var divisor = 100;

    var nums = [];
    var n = Math.ceil(number/divisor)*divisor;
    for(;n<=limit;n=n+increment) {
        nums.push(n);
    }
    return nums.join();
};
```

Input : 758

Outputs : "800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800,2000"